# Taking user input matched to an array to draw onto canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

EDIT: This is javascript not jQuery related.

New to jQuery so this may be basic. Am trying to use jquery to draw onto my canvas element if the string input by the user is matched against an element in my array. Here is what I have:

```
<body>
<canvas id="c4" width="300px" height="200px" style="border:1px solid black">Not supported</canvas>

<script>
    //main problem having is simply defining the jQuery function correctly
    function draw(){
        var c = document.getElementById("c4");
        if (canvas.getContext){
        var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
        ctx.fillStyle = "lightgrey";
                    //(x,y,values)
        ctx.fillRect(0,0,300,200);
                // (x, y) (20,15) is starting point
        ctx.moveTo(20,15);
        ctx.lineTo(20,120);


        ctx.moveTo(20,15);
        ctx.lineTo(100,15);


        ctx.moveTo(100,15);
        ctx.lineTo(100,45);
        ctx.stroke();



        ctx.moveTo(100,45);
        ctx.arc(99,50,8,0,2*Math.PI);
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.fill();

        ctx.moveTo(20,120);
        ctx.lineTo(65,120);
        ctx.stroke();

        ctx.moveTo(20,40);
        ctx.lineTo(40,15);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
    }               
</script>

    <input type="text" id="input1">
    <button onclick="myJsFunction()">$</button>

        <script>
         function myJsFunction(){
             // adding this in later
         }
        </script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where are you going wrong? Are you getting an error?

Comment: It just doesn't do any of the canvas drawing

Comment: do you have any ideas?

Comment: there is no jQuery in your code... also remember to use beginPath() when you want to stroke a new line (after last stroke and before moveTo). To make it draw you must call the function `draw()`...

Comment: Yeah just found the function call was the issue - noob error. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A short summary as answer:

- There is absolutely no jQuery in your code..
- You are defining the draw operations inside a function called `draw()`. You must call this function to make it draw.
- You need to use `beginPath()` after each stroke operation or the old path will be drawn next time you call stroke() together with the new path added after stroke was called.